# How Do I connect to a proxy in windows 7?

Tags: proxy

I can't seem to log in to my proxies through the internet settings in windows 7. My proxies have a username and a password and theres no place to write them in the place where I log into my proxies (internet settings-->lan)
thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this solution from answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adding-credentials-to-windows-proxy-settings/d6fdab82-6163-4aad-8133-43f7706ceb9c?auth=1)? It's for Windows 10, but I'd think it should work on Win 7, too.

Comment: Hey, I tried it now but when I enter IP sites it still shows the same IP address as before.